# How to add File name at recently opened file File menu

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to write a QML app that adds the latest opened files from `FileDialog` to the main menu. I'm currently following [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menu.html#items-prop) documentation example but the problem is that I can't understand how to pass the file name of an opened file.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar : MenuBar
    {
        Menu
        {
            id: recentFilesMenu
            Instantiator
                {
                    model: recentFilesMenu
                    MenuItem
                    {
                        text: model.fileName // I neeed to pass name of opned file here
                    }
                    onObjectAdded: recentFilesMenu.insertItem(index, object)
                }

            title: "File"
            MenuItem
            {
                text: "Open"
                onTriggered: fileDialog.visible = true

            }


            MenuItem
            {
                text: "Exit"
            }
        }


    }

    FileDialog
        {
            id: fileDialog
            title: "Oooopen"
            onAccepted:
            {
              // Here is problem
            recentFilesMenu.objectName = fileDialog.fileUrls
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, [`Instantiator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-instantiator.html#model-prop) accepts the most common types of models - both C++ and QML ones. In the documentation example such an information is missing, probably to not force the usage of a specific one. An actual implementation can relay on `ListModel`. In this case the model would expose a `fileName` role used as the actual menu item.

Following this approach the result would be something like the following code. Mind that the `url`s are prepended with information which can be easily removed (see for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26868237/2538363)).

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar : MenuBar {

        Menu {
            id: recentFilesMenu

            title: "File"

            MenuItem {
                text: "Open"
                onTriggered: fileDialog.visible = true
            }

            MenuSeparator { }

            Instantiator {
                model: ListModel { id: files }

                MenuItem { text: fileName }

                onObjectAdded: recentFilesMenu.insertItem(index, object)
                onObjectRemoved: recentFilesMenu.removeItem(object)
            }

            MenuSeparator { visible: files.count > 0 }

            MenuItem { text: "Exit" }
        }
    }

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        title: "Open"
        onAccepted: {
            for(var i = 0; i < fileDialog.fileUrls.length; ++i)
                files.append({fileName: fileDialog.fileUrls[i]})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I was doing this with a Component and executing createObject and adding the object to the Menu I was using.  Using an Instantiator is much cleaner process.

Answer (score 1):

There is a widgets version of this kind of feature:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-recentfiles-example.html

But the descriptive help is non-existent.  Looking through the code here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-recentfiles-mainwindow-cpp.html

You will see that it stores a QStringList of a list of recent files in QSettings, and loads everything into an array of QActions.

Follow through the mainWindow.cpp for all the references to

```
enum { MaxRecentFiles = 5 };
QAction *recentFileActs[MaxRecentFiles];
```

And you should have some good ideas about how to do something similar in QML.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a finite number of recent files that you want to display. That being said, you can implement x number of [MenuItems](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menuitem.html) and set the text to QStringList[i] implemented as a [Q_PROPERTY](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html) in a C++ class. Then, you can manipulate the QStringList elements(size, order) on your C++ class.