# QML: how to get file baseName

Tags: qml, qt-creator

How I can extract file baseName from full file URL?

```
FileDialog
    {
        id: fileDialog
        title: "Oooopen"
        onAccepted:
        {
        console.log(fileUrl)    
        }

    }
```

`fileUrl` do not have properties like `baseName` I tried to googling, but without success

Comment: You can expose custom class from C++ to QML with functionality of QFileInfo since it isn't derived from QObject and cannot be exposed to QML directly. Or just do it with Regexp, for example `fileUrl.toString().replace(/\\/g,'/').replace(/.*\//, '')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the path from a QML url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927850/get-the-path-from-a-qml-url)

Answer (score 5):

You could define your own `basename` function

```
function basename(str)
{
    return (str.slice(str.lastIndexOf("/")+1))
}


FileDialog
{
    id: fileDialog
    title: "Oooopen"
    onAccepted:
    {
        console.log(basename(fileUrl.toString()))    
    }
}
```

Comment: In Qt 5.10 (may be in early version too) this function looks like: `return (String(str).slice(String(str).lastIndexOf("/")+1))`